# Как передать объект из одного компонента в другой?

Tags: reactjs

// Это у меня компонент Goods

```
function Goods () {
const [cart, setCart] = useState({})
// Я получаю объект при нажатие кнопки
console.log(cart)
render (
// Тут код который выводит товары на страницу
// Это кнопка которая заносит в cart объект
<button onClick={()=> {return setCart(roll)} className={styles.btn__add} type='button'>Add</button>
)
}
```

Как мне setState cart-object передать с этого компонента Goods в компонент Cart. Добавить товар в корзину
Пробую импортировать с Goods в Cart

```
import {cart} from '../goodsCreate/Goods'
// Выдает ошибку
//ERROR in ./src/components/content/cartCreate/Cart.jsx 14:18-22
export 'cart' (imported as 'cart') was not found in '../goodsCreate/Goods' (possible exports: default)
```

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно завести стейт в родителе двух этих компонентов и передавать либо пропсами (если не большая вложенность получится) либо через `reducer`.

Comment: Передать что-то в компонент можно несколькими способами... Пропсами. Используя контекст. Используя некий стейтовый менеджер.

Comment: @ksa Да, получилось с помощью контекста, теперь возникла другая проблема)